# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null.active

Tags: javascript, typeerror

It's a sign in button and a form which both contain in one id `mainButton` box, but each of them has different `z-index`. When click the `signIn-btn`, the form will show out. But I occur a problem that it doesn't work when click the button, and the chrome Dev Tools shows

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null'

seemly something wrong with my javascript about `openForm()`.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('mainButton');

var openForm=function() {
    button.className = "active";
};
var checkInput = function(input) {
    if (input.value.length > 0) {
        input.className = "active";
    } else {
        input.className = "";
    }
};
```

```css
#mainButton .active {
     box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 15px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
#mainButton .active .signIn-form {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="mainButton">
    <div class="signIn-btn" onclick="openForm();">
        Sign In
    </div>
    <div class="signIn-form">
        <div class="close-btn" onclick="closeForm()">
            ✘
        </div>
        <div class="form-title">
            Sign In
        </div>
        <div class="formInput-group">
            <input type="text" id="name" onblur="checkInput(this)">
            <label for="name">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="formInput-group">
            <input type="password" id="password" onblur="checkInput(this)">
            <label for="password">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-btn">
            Go
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: will this work? parent.button.className = "active";

Comment: I don't see any errors in this code snippet. Are you sure you placed your JS *after* the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is additional space in your CSS selector. It should be:

```
#mainButton.active {
     box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 15px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
#mainButton.active .signIn-form {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

Also make sure that your script is placed after the rest of HTML.

Corrected code snippet:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('mainButton');

var openForm=function() {
    button.className = "active";
};
var checkInput = function(input) {
    if (input.value.length > 0) {
        input.className = "active";
    } else {
        input.className = "";
    }
};
```

```css
#mainButton.active {
     box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 15px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
#mainButton.active .signIn-form {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="mainButton">
    <div class="signIn-btn" onclick="openForm();">
        Sign In
    </div>
    <div class="signIn-form">
        <div class="close-btn" onclick="closeForm()">
            ✘
        </div>
        <div class="form-title">
            Sign In
        </div>
        <div class="formInput-group">
            <input type="text" id="name" onblur="checkInput(this)">
            <label for="name">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="formInput-group">
            <input type="password" id="password" onblur="checkInput(this)">
            <label for="password">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-btn">
            Go
        </div>
    </div>
```